# Passing an NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, nsdate

I'm new to the iPhone and objective-c and I am still trying to get my head around ownership of objects so bear with me.

I have a DOBViewController that has a datepicker on it. I have created a custom init method:

```
-(id)initWithInitialDate(NSDate *)initialDate;
```

Another view controller has a date instance declared (NSDate *dob) that holds a value. I would like to pass this to the DOBViewController so that it can scroll the datepicker to the passed value.

Here is the custom init method:

```
- (id)initWithInitialDate:(NSDate *)initialDate {
// Initialise ourselves
self = [super init];

// Set the date of the date picker
if (initialDate != nil) {
    datePicker.date = initialDate;
}
else {
    // Set it to today
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
}

return self;
```

}

This is how I am sending the dob NSDate object:

```
DOBViewController *dobViewController = [[DOBViewController alloc] initWithInitialDate:dob];
```

Where dob is a variable of type NSDate that is declared in the header file.

This doesn't seem to work as initialDate is always NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `datePicker` outlet isn't loaded yet by the time the `init...` method returns.  You should save the `NSDate` into an instance variable, and then do the setting in a more appropriate method, like `viewDidLoad`.